# How do I install Custom Workflow Activities in the GAC

Tags: .net, gac

I am trying to figure out the best way to take a Workflow Activity Library I've created with custom activities and put it in the GAC to allow any developer on my team to add it to their toolbox and thereby use it.

A Nuget Package is referenced in the solution/project itself.  I would rather not have a DLL in every project this thing is used in, plus the Toolbox is specific to a path that I would like to be 1 common place it pulls from like the install ones out of the box.

Do I need to make an install package that will do this?  or is there an easier or better way?

Thanks!

Comment: Really has nothing to do with WF4.  Did you [read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79.aspx)?  Any issues with what it says?

Comment: yeah I did install the created Assembly into the GAC but it didn't do what I expected it to.  The only way I've found to make this work as it needs to to have all references and the activities in the toolbox is to add the project in as a part of my solution.  Once built the activities automatically add themselves to the Toolbox under a category that matches the namespace.

Comment: You would have to add them manually anyhow.  Thankfully, VS doesn't scan every assembly in the gac for toolbox-able classes every time you access the toolbox.  It would drag forever.